# jquery issues with tr click changes checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

My condition: I have a checkbox inside `<tr>`, written in `<asp:repeater>` on an user control, placed in an aspx page.

My goal: when `<tr>` is clicked, JQuery changes (or specifically, toggles) the checkbox checked attribute as well as the css class of the `<tr>` itself.

I've tried several methods, and so far, only this one works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/WnbNC/
, but unfortunately, all of the checkboxes are toggled instead of only the selected one, just like the example on jsfiddle.net. moreover, if I clicked on the checkbox itself, all of the other checkboxes are checked instead of the clicked one.

What I've done:

```
    $(".moduleTableItem").click(function (e) {
        // Toggles CSS
        if (!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass("tr.active")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("tr.active");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("tr.active");
        }
        // Toggles Checkbox
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, value) {
            return !value;
        });
```

ASP:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repModuleGeneral" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="trModuleGeneral" class="moduleTableItem" runat="server">
                            <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbxSelect" class="cbxSelect"  runat="server" autopostback="false" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNo" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

This is my first question. Please let me know if my question is somewhat unclear. Any code snippets or working solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "when is clicked" - when what is clicked? the checkbox or the buttons?

Comment: I think you used the wrong selector. ":checkbox" means all checkboxes. If you want the specified one, you should use selector which can identify it, like id or something else.Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnbNC/145/) and notice the last one.

Comment: also, show us your HTML for the <tr>

Comment: @hungerpain : oh, terribly sorry, I didn't understand that < tr > is not displayed in SO

Comment: "when <tr> is clicked," - Show us the HTML in this `<tr/>`

Comment: @Clxy : i put those checkboxes inside asp:repeater, which means all id are generated from server. if there is a way for me to identify the selected checkbox, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, value) {
```

To

```
$(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, value) {
```

`this` used here will point to the current clicked `tr`.

This wont work if you directly click on the checkbox. Why, you ask? Because the `checkbox` lies inside `tr`, to which you've assigned a `click` event to. So, when click on a checkbox which is `unchecked`, these two actions are triggered :

1. Checkbox selected because of default checkbox action - checkbox set to `true`.
2. The click on the `tr` is triggered. You've got a checkbox `prop` event there. Reverts the selection done by default action.

So its a basic counter action, which cancels the default actions of the checkbox. To rectify this, you'll have to check if the default target is NOT a checkbox and then run the `prop` function :

```
$(".moduleTableItem").click(function (e) {    

    // Toggles CSS
    if (!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass("tr.active")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("tr.active");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("tr.active");
    }
    //check here
    if (!$(e.target).is(":checkbox")) {
        // Toggles Checkbox
        $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, value) {
            return !value;
        });
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Kph8M/

But, just as a side thought, if you have control over IDs generated over the checkboxes, you could assign the same id as the `for` attribute in the label. Your HTML would look like this :

```
 <tr class="moduleTableItem">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbxSelect1" class="cbxSelect" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="cbxSelect1">Text</label>
        </td>
 </tr>
```

Not the `id` attribute of the checkbox and the `for` attribute of the label. A lot of hassle will be solved by this. And you could use the `change` event of the check box. Also, did some optimisations to your code. It would look something like this :

```
$(".moduleTableItem :checkbox").change(function (e) {
    //cache this - you are using it more than once.
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // check if class is active - I took away if..else and made it ternary
    var bg = $tr.hasClass("tr.active") ? 'red': 'blue';   
    //set css and toggleClass. Anyway you're switching everytime. Why not use toggle?
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', bg).toggleClass("tr.active");
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Kph8M/4/

Comment: Well thank you, it works, finally! Both the css and checkbox are toggled. But there is one thing: When i click on the checkbox, the css changes, but the checkbox itself is not. Another undesired result happens when i start clicking on the checkbox then on the <tr>, or start with <tr> then go on the checkbox. It would be cool if this case can also be handled.

Comment: it would be great if you made a sample fiddle. remove the asp: controls and just make a template

Comment: @shihandrana check my answer. Hope it answers your question.